# Why is my php variable not outputting with javascript alert?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have a PHP variable which I am trying to pass into a javascript function. Using pure PHP I am to echo the desired string output, but when I shove it into a variable and output it in javascript it doesn't work.

It seems javascript doesn't seem to see anything at all.

Here's the code:

```
<?php $a = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post -> ID ); ?>
<?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $a ); ?>
<?php $b = $img[0]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = <?php echo $b; ?>;
alert(myVar);
</script>
```

Whilst this is just a test piece of code I'm trying to make work, the results of which I am trying to make work with something like this:

```
<?php $a = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post -> ID ); ?>
<?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $a ); ?>
<?php $b = $img[0]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".imgWindow").backstretch("<?php echo $b; ?>"); 
</script>
```

There's clearly some underlining principal of PHP and Javascript I must be missing.

Enlighten me please. Help appreciated.

Comment: Don't show us PHP and say that JavaScript doesn't work. Either show us the generated JavaScript and ask why *that* doesn't work, or show us the PHP, the generated JavaScript and the JavaScript you expect and ask why you aren't getting the JS you expect.

Comment: The first code needs quotation. var myVar = "<?php echo $b; ?>";

Comment: @Quentin I don't quite understand what you mean? but Ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php $a = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post -> ID ); ?>
<?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $a ); ?>
<?php $b = $img[0]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = '<?php echo $b; ?>';
alert(myVar);
</script>
```

You have to wrap the value in quotes for non-integer values.

Alternatively, assign like this:

```
var myVar = '<?=$b;?>';
```

Answer (score 3):

if it's a string "image name" use quotes

```
var myVar = '<?php echo $b; ?>';
```